# Image resizes when inserted in PdfCell

Tags: image, itext

I'm trying to create Pdf using itextsharp. I have added one table conataining two columns one containing text and other image. I want to have constant image size

1. My Image automatically resizes if the text present in another cell increases and image present in other cell has different sizes

   ```
     for (int i = 0; i < visitInfo.VisitsiteComplience.Count; ++i)
       {

           cellprop.Colspan = 1;
           cellprop.Pharse = visitInfo.VisitsiteComplience[i].Compliencedescription;
           cellprop.BaseColor = null;
           table.AddCell(AddCelltoTable(cellprop));
           yesicon.ScaleAbsolute(35f, 35f);
           noicon.ScaleAbsolute(35f, 35f);

           if (visitInfo.VisitsiteComplience[i].Status == "1")
           {

               statuscell.AddElement(new Chunk(noicon, 0, 0));

           }
           else
           {

              // statuscell.AddElement(new Chunk(noicon, 0, 0));
           }


          statuscell.FixedHeight = 10;


           //headerLeftCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
           table.AddCell(statuscell);
       }
   ```

[image]
2. Then I changed the code but now Image size increases and occupies full cell

```
     for (int i = 0; i < visitInfo.VisitsiteComplience.Count; ++i)
        {

            cellprop.Colspan = 1;
            cellprop.Pharse = visitInfo.VisitsiteComplience[i].Compliencedescription;
            cellprop.BaseColor = null;
            table.AddCell(AddCelltoTable(cellprop));
            yesicon.ScaleAbsolute(35f, 35f);
            noicon.ScaleAbsolute(35f, 35f);

            if (visitInfo.VisitsiteComplience[i].Status == "1")
            {

                statuscell.AddElement(new Chunk(noicon, 0, 0));

            }
            else
            {

               // statuscell.AddElement(new Chunk(noicon, 0, 0));
            }





            //headerLeftCell.Border = PdfPCell.NO_BORDER;
            table.AddCell(statuscell);
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I think you're scaling the image yourself like this: `noicon.ScaleAbsolute(35f, 35f);`

It also puzzles me why you're wrapping the image inside a `Chunk`. You can create a `PdfPCell` that takes an `Image` as parameter as well as a `Bool` to defines whether or not iText should scale the `Image`. See page 109 of the book [iText in Action](http://itextpdf.com/book) (of which I'm the author) and take a look at the XMen example of [chapter 4](http://tinyurl.com/iiacsCH04).

Answer (score 0):

```
Image image = Image.getInstance("D:/star.png");

PdfPCell cell = new PdfPCell();

cell.setFixedHeight(40f);

cell.addElement(image);

table.addCell(cell);
```

Comment: Would be better to add a description what the code does/how it solves the issue, not just code